# WSAGetLastError 10038 in a C++ client

Tags: c++, sockets

I create a C++ client that connect to a C++ server.
It connect and send correctly data to a server.
I create a separate thread to receive data from the server , and here is the problem that I can't figure it out.
I get this error:

```
WSAGetLastError 10038
```

I find that this error because the descriptor is not a socket.

The server send method work correcty, I test it with a telnet client.

This is my client code:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int hsock;
void *SocketHandler(void*);

int main(int argv, char** argc){

    //The port and address you want to connect to
    int host_port= 2000;//1101;
    char* host_name="10.188.126.198";
    pthread_t recept;


    //Initialize socket support WINDOWS ONLY!
    unsigned short wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD( 2, 2 );
    err = WSAStartup( wVersionRequested, &wsaData );
    if ( err != 0 || ( LOBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 2 ||
            HIBYTE( wsaData.wVersion ) != 2 )) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find useable sock dll %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    //Initialize sockets and set any options

    int * p_int ;
    hsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(hsock == -1){
        printf("Error initializing socket %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    p_int = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p_int = 1;
    if( (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 )||
        (setsockopt(hsock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char*)p_int, sizeof(int)) == -1 ) ){
        printf("Error setting options %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        free(p_int);
        return 0;
    }
    free(p_int);

    //Connect to the server
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);

    memset(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_name);

    int *csock ;
            csock = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    if( (*csock =connect( hsock, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr))) == SOCKET_ERROR ){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting socket %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 0;
        }

    cout<<"Client connect to :"<< htons(host_port)<<endl;

    //Create thread to receive data from the server
// the problem is here as I think
    pthread_create(&recept,NULL,SocketHandler,(void *)csock);


/// Send data to the server    
    char buffer[1024];
    int buffer_len = 1024;
    int bytecount;

    int c;

    while(true){
             memset(buffer, '\0', buffer_len);
            for(char* p=buffer ; (c=getch())!=13 ; p++){
                printf("%c", c);
                *p = c;
            }


                if( (bytecount=send(hsock, buffer, strlen(buffer),0))==SOCKET_ERROR){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    return 0;
                }
                printf("Sent bytes %d\n", bytecount);

    }

    closesocket(hsock);

return 0;

}
void *SocketHandler(void* lp){
    int *csock= (int*)lp;
    cout<<"Start Listening Thread"<<endl;

    char buffer[1024];
    int buffer_len = 1024;
    int bytecount;
        memset(buffer, 0, buffer_len);

    while(1){

    memset(buffer, 0, buffer_len);
    if((bytecount = recv(*csock, buffer, buffer_len, 0))==SOCKET_ERROR){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        break;
    }
        printf("Received bytes %d\nReceived string \"%s\"\n", bytecount, buffer);

    }

    free(csock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check [connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625(v=vs.85).aspx)'s return value: _If no error occurs, connect returns zero. Otherwise, it returns SOCKET_ERROR, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling WSAGetLastError._ You are assigning it to `*csock` and then perform a `recv` on it.

Comment: The client connect correctly as I said, and can send data to the server. The problem is on a thread for the recv method

Comment: Exactly. `connect` succeeds, and returns _0_. So: `*csock = 0;` Then you have `if((bytecount = recv(*csock, buffer,...` You're calling `recv` on _0_ which is typically _stdin_.

Comment: yes, I understand what was the problem now, Thanks @CristiFati

Comment: NP, hope you got it working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function 'connect' returns result, not socket handle (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Change it to:

```
...
if (connect(hsock, (struct sockaddr*)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting socket %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    return 0;
}

*csock = hsock;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter that you send to the thread is the `csock`...

```
int *csock ;
csock = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
...
pthread_create(&recept,NULL,SocketHandler,(void *)csock);
```

and then you use the `csock` as a the socket (in the thread)...

```
int *csock= (int*)lp;
...
if((bytecount = recv(*csock, buffer, buffer_len, 0))==SOCKET_ERROR) {
```

I think that you need to use the `hsock` as your socket and not the `*csock`...

BTW: 
In windows you should call it a SOCKET and not int...

Hope it helps...